# Playlist Keeps Loading in Video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js, playlist, m3u8, live-video

We are using m3u8 playlist for playing live video on web page using video.js(v4.12.7) and on some other devices. Our playlist doesn't contain #EXT-X-ENDLIST (which marks playlist end). This had to be done to support live video for other devices.

The issue is- Even after clicking pause button the playlist keeps loading. video segments don't download anymore but playlist does.